# Speed up model predictions when using cron job

Tags: r, cron, xgboost

I have a set of XGBoost models that needs to run on a minutely interval using predict().

When I set this up to run with a cron job (using the cronR package), the predictions run very slow compared to running it manually from my RStudio environment.

My intuition is that the manual run benefits from running in the live environment with the models already loaded into memory, while the cron job lives in a separate environment and ends up doing all the heavy work each time it runs.

Is there a way to make the cron job work with the environment pre loaded into memory (if this is correct) or any other workaround to speed the predictions up?

EDIT: Updated question to better reflect the nature of the problem.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/save-and-load-rdata-workspace-files-in-r/

Comment: @Dave2e The workspace is > 1GB and needs to be run on a minutely interval. Could we somehow keep it in memory between each cron run to skip the loading?

Comment: If you are running the script minutely, why not write an infinite loop and let it run continuously in the background?  Use sysSleep() to add a pause between cycles.

Comment: Yes, an infinity loop is the best solution I've found so far. I was hoping to find a way to do it with cron jobs, it just seems more robust to me. I will settle with the infinity loop until eventually a cron solution pops up.